# how many bluetooth pairing can be made?

Tags: bluetooth

I have an android phone and I want it to communicate with 10 bluetooth modules, not simultaneously. I know that a master device can have 7 slaves for bluetooth connection. does it mean "pairing"?

The question is can I have my phone paired with 10 bluetooth devices? Then send them data seperately?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no set limit on the number of pairings possible for a device, except for any limitations made by the platform or bluetooth software stack (eg. limited storage).

Answer (score 6):

> does it mean "pairing"?

Bluetooth pairing and connecting are two separate operations.

When two Bluetooth devices pair, they will exchange Bluetooth addresses and encryption keys.  If pairing is successful, it allows the devices to connect to each other at a later time.

When two bluetooth devices connect, the profiles are established (a2dp if a speaker, hfp if headset, etc), and they can communicate.

Sometimes there is confusion between pairing and connecting since most smartphones automatically connect after detecting a successful pairing.

Pairing is just done once, typically when you buy a Bluetooth product.  Connection is done whenever you use the product.

> The question is can I have my phone paired with 10 bluetooth devices?
>   Then send them data seperately?

As mentioned in the other answer, the maximum number of paired devices is platform dependent, it varies from product to product, but there is no set limit.  The maximum number of connected devices (that you could send/receive data concurrently to) is 7 according to the Bluetooth specification.

Comment: Can you provide the source of the 7 device limitation?